# Can I license GPLv2 or v3 for Oracle JDK as the java compiler?

Tags: java, open-source, licensing, pdfbox

I am using Java for developing an application and it is very important for me to make this application Open Source. I am stuck with two licenses Apachev2 and GPL(v2/v3).

1. I am definitely not charging for the source code.
2. I will be putting up the complete source on Github for the provision of the source code link.

I am using Apache PDFbox (http://pdfbox.apache.org/) for my application involves dealing with PDF files. This jar bundle is licensed under Apachev2 license.

I really need some insight and guidance on how to select the license for my Application and also feel free to tell me about other licenses which are better for my current situation.
Also I need to know if I can use any of these above mentioned licenses, with Oracle Java compiler. Thanks.

Comment: If you're talking about forking OpenJDK, that is going to be very difficult, especially due to the patent issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to advise whether Apachev2 or GPL2/3 is best for you.  To a significant degree, it depends on your beliefs about the politics of open source, and whether you believe (and care<sup>1</sup>) that some people won't use your code if it is GPL'ed.

Here are some resources:

- The Open Source Initiative site has information on a number of popular open source licenses: http://opensource.org/licenses
- The GNU site has lots of material on the various flavours of the GPL, what they mean, and compatibility with other open source licenses: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.html

But the good news is that either Apachev2 or GPL of various flavours would be suitable for a project that used PDFBox.

**FOLLOW-UP:**

> I meant to ask weather I can put a GPL license on Java Source code esp when I know that I am going to compile it with Oracle JDK which is I believe not open source

No proper open source license would place restrictions on the compilers that you (or someone else) can use to compile your code.  GPL is no exception.

GPL does place restrictions on derivative works: the derivative work is covered by the GPL. But that's OK.  A binary produced by compiling your source code is a derivative work of your source code ... but not a derivative work of the compiler.  (Or at least not in the sense that "derivative work" is used in Copyright Law.)

Finally, while Oracle Java is not open source, OpenJDK is 100% GPL.

---

<sup>1 - FWIW, I don't care.  The reasons why people / organizations / companies "cannot" use GPL tend to be self-serving.</sup>

Comment: I meant to ask weather I can put a GPL license on Java Source code esp when I know that I am going to compile it with Oracle JDK which is I believe not open source

Comment: @dguitarbite Can you add that sentence (or something like it) to your question? Reading the question on its own, your intent wasn't as clear to me as this sentence puts it.

Comment: yes I am sorry for late reply. I was having exams.